# Woocommerce - adding variations to variations

Tags: plugins

I am setting up a store whereby I have variations for products.

I want to configure it so that when a customer selects a variation they see a range of other variations for that variation.

As an example: they're buying a product and selecting a colour. If they choose to have black they can't have any further options. If they choose the colour as white they are then given additional variation options.

Is this even possible within Woocommerce?

Thanks in advance,
Stu.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using [Gravity Forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/) for this. You will also need the [Woocommerce Gravity Forms add-on.](http://www.woothemes.com/products/gravity-forms-add-ons/)